# convert url string to array php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I pass with jquery ajax as data array the following structure

```
 $_POST['data'][0] = 'results[]=stein&results[]=schere&results[]=stein&results[]=schere&results[]=stein'

 $_POST['data'][1] = '9b2c1230757e4354b384c5c93e8e8f26'
```

How do I say to php to interpret `$_POST['data'][0]` as array. What I would like to get is `array(1 =>'stein', 2=>'schere'...)`

Comment: this should work $_POST['data'][0][results]...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) — Parses the string into variables

```
$str = "results[]=stein&results[]=schere&results[]=stein&results[]=schere&results[]=stein";
parse_str($str, $output);

echo $output['results'][0]; // stein
```

Live [**CodePad**](http://codepad.org/rqgLuepL)

Answer (score 0):

use `parse_str()`..

```
parse_str($_POST['data'][0]);

print_r($results);
echo $results[0];  //stein;
echo $results[1];  //schere;
```